# Display model error for date in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a Rails model with a date attribute, named `date_assigned`. If a user enters `111111` in a form and clicks submit, Rails seems to typecast this which results in a nil value. I have validation so that this will add an error to the model. So in my controller, I instead render the `:edit` action, but I cannot display the invalid value so the user can correct it. Is there a way for me to do this? I'll give an example scenario below

app/views/blog_posts/edit.html.erb

```
<input type="text" name="blog_post[date_assigned]" />
```

app/controllers/blog_posts_controller.rb

```
@blog_post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
if @blog_post.update blog_post_params # fails because of validation
  # save
else
  flash.now[:error] = @blog_post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
  render :edit
end
```

When displaying the edit view, I cannot figure out how to display the invalid value.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a text field input. What about a date input? I also notice your comment `#save`. You won't have to save the instance because the update method does that.

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to use a date input, but figured that there must be some way to display the invalid value back in the text field when using a text field. Yup, sorry about the #save comment, I was rewriting the example on the fly and where the #save comment is, it's just the redirect to the edit_blog_post_path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your @blog_post.errors and than send it to view. 
Something like that:

```
@blog_post = BlogPost.find(params[:id])
if @blog_post.update blog_post_params # fails because of validation
  # save
else
    object.errors.add(:date_assigned, "Your data is incorrect" + (@blog_post.date_assigned).to_s)
    logger.debug "#{@blog_post.errors.get(:date_assigned)}" # Check your console, it will show you input from user.
    flash.now[:error] = @blog_post.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    render :edit
end
```

You can find more information about add method in ActiveRecord Errors here - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add

If you have some questions feel fre to ask.

Comment: But my problem is that I would like to display the invalid value in the form field where they entered it. When I call `if @blog_post.update blog_post_params`, that field is set to nil.